# Separating numbers from symbols in lists; python

Tags: python, list

I got an assignment, but I'm stuck, I need to analyze a list and separate the numbers from the symbols and create 2 different lists, adding numbers to one list and symbols to the other. Right now I have this list:

```
[1, '+', '(', 2, '+', 3, ')']
```

what I need is to have the other 2 lists look like this:

```
numbers=[1,2,3]
symbols=['+','(','+',')']
```

while maintaining the original list intact.
The code I have so far is:

```
def separador():
    numbers=[]
    symbols=[]
    countlen=len(out1)
    listcount=0
    while listcount!=countlen:
        pos=out1[listcount]
        if pos==int:
            numbers.append(pos)
        elif sim=='+':
            symbols.append(pos)  
    print(numbers)
    print(symbols)
```

I'm trying to analyze each part of the list by comparing a counter with the length of the list, then, each one is compared as if is a sting or a number, then it should be added to the correct list. but it's not working. help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers are integers, symbols are simply strings:

```
numbers = [i for i in the_list if isinstance(i, int)]
symbols = [i for i in the_list if isinstance(i, str)]
```

Comment: If you'd like to support floats just add an or in the condition.

Comment: isinstance can take tuples, so you could just do `isinstance(i, (int, float))`

Comment: you can also support floats more succinctly like this: `isinstance(i, (int, float))`

Comment: Thanks dude! That did the trick! I can continue with the rest now!

Comment: Sorry, forgot about it.